# observer on route data will be fired even if value has not changed

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

We are changing our URL by changing the data attribute of app-route.

This is our app-route

```
<app-route
  pattern="/:view/:person/:year/:state/:area/:detail"
  data="{{routeData}}"></app-route>
```

E.g. a dropdown with years will change the year path of the url with

```
this.set('routeData.year', '2016');
```

All this works fine. We run into problems as we use observers for sub properties of the routeData. E.g.

```
obsevers: [
  '_routeDataYearChanged(routeData.year)',
  '_routeDataPersonChanged(routeData.person)',
]
```

If we now change the year, the _routeDataYearChanged observer will be called. But also the _routeDataPersonChanged observer. Nevertheless the person never changed. Why are all observers of routeData sub properties will be called, nevertheless only one sub property will be changed?

Comment: What is the value of `routeData` with you change the value of year, you can add a function to observe and log it